Why do these #include RcppArmadillo cause R to compile Rcpp code with C++11 instead of C++17 on Ubuntu 22.04?
I have recently started using a machine with Ubuntu 22.04 and I find that my existing (windows) .cpp files are no longer compiling with sourceCpp. The issue is that I require a compilation with at least C++14, and in fact I can successful compile the files using sourceCpp if I explicitly set the flag // [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp14")]].
My question is why R has chosen to use a lower version of C++ when C++17 is available and seems to be the default in simple programs? Compare the following two sample .cpp files, which seem to differ only in the inclusion of the RcppArmadillo libraries:
# test_stan.cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends(rstan)]]
#include <stan/math.hpp>
#include <iostream>
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int simple() {
    std::cout << "log normal(1 | 2, 3)="
    << stan::math::normal_log(1, 2, 5)
    << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

# test_stan_with_more_complicated...

// [[Rcpp::depends(rstan)]]
#include <stan/math.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int simple() {
    std::cout << "log normal(1 | 2, 3)="
              << stan::math::normal_log(1, 2, 5)
              << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Running sourceCpp results in the following calls to the C++ compiler respectively:
g++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/"
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen/include/"
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen/include/unsupported"
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/StanHeaders/include/src/"
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/StanHeaders/include/"
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppParallel/include/"
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rstan/include" -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG
-DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS  -DBOOST_PENDING_INTEGER_LOG2_HPP
-DSTAN_THREADS  -DUSE_STANC3 -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS
-DBOOST_PHOENIX_NO_VARIADIC_EXPRESSION  -D_HAS_AUTO_PTR_ETC=0  -include
'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/fun/Eigen.hpp'
-D_REENTRANT -DRCPP_PARALLEL_USE_TBB=1
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rstan/include"
-I"/home/rdpdp/Desktop/data/debug_gcc_version"     -fpic  -g -O2
-ffile-prefix-map=/build/r-base-H8urij/r-base-4.4.0=. -fstack-protector-strong
-Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -c
test_stan.cpp -o test_stan.o

and
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/"
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen/include/"
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen/include/unsupported"
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/StanHeaders/include/src/"
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/StanHeaders/include/"
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppParallel/include/"
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rstan/include" -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG
-DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS  -DBOOST_PENDING_INTEGER_LOG2_HPP
-DSTAN_THREADS  -DUSE_STANC3 -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS
-DBOOST_PHOENIX_NO_VARIADIC_EXPRESSION  -D_HAS_AUTO_PTR_ETC=0  -include
'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/fun/Eigen.hpp'
-D_REENTRANT -DRCPP_PARALLEL_USE_TBB=1  -I../inst/include
-fopenmp  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rstan/include"
-I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include"
-I"/home/rdpdp/Desktop/data/debug_gcc_version"     -fpic  -g -O2
-ffile-prefix-map=/build/r-base-H8urij/r-base-4.4.0=. -fstack-protector-strong
-Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
-c test_stan_with_more_complicated_includes.cpp -o
test_stan_with_more_complicated_includes.o

Apart from addition RcppArmadillo and fopenmp flag, the only difference seems to be in the C++ version:

My machine has the following compilers:
 dpkg --list | grep compiler
ii  g++                                        4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1                       amd64        GNU C++ compiler
ii  g++-11                                     11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04                   amd64        GNU C++ compiler
ii  gcc                                        4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1                       amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-11                                     11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04                   amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gfortran                                   4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1                       amd64        GNU Fortran 95 compiler
ii  gfortran-11                                11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04                   amd64        GNU Fortran compiler
ii  libllvm14:amd64                            1:14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1                     amd64        Modular compiler and toolchain technologies, runtime library
ii  libllvm15:amd64                            1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.3               amd64        Modular compiler and toolchain technologies, runtime library
ii  libxkbcommon0:amd64                        1.4.0-1                                 amd64        library interface to the XKB compiler - shared library
ii  rpcsvc-proto                               1.4.2-0ubuntu6                          amd64        RPC protocol compiler and definitions

R sessionInfo() excerpt is:
R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0 
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0


attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] vctrs_0.6.5        cli_3.6.2          rlang_1.1.3        generics_0.1.3    
 [5] jsonlite_1.8.8     RcppParallel_5.1.7 glue_1.7.0         colorspace_2.1-0  
 [9] rstan_2.32.6       gridExtra_2.3      pkgbuild_1.4.4     stats4_4.4.0      
[13] scales_1.3.0       fansi_1.0.6        StanHeaders_2.32.7 grid_4.4.0        
[17] munsell_0.5.1      tibble_3.2.1       lifecycle_1.0.4    QuickJSR_1.1.3    
[21] inline_0.3.19      compiler_4.4.0     codetools_0.2-19   dplyr_1.1.4       
[25] pkgconfig_2.0.3    Rcpp_1.0.12        R6_2.5.1           tidyselect_1.2.1  
[29] utf8_1.2.4         parallel_4.4.0     pillar_1.9.0       magrittr_2.0.3    
[33] loo_2.7.0          tools_4.4.0        gtable_0.3.5       matrixStats_1.3.0 
[37] ggplot2_3.5.1 


In general, this  is set by R as described in Writing R Extensions.  R has been moving up the default compilers since release R 4.0.0 and if I recall correctly has been at C++17 since maybe R 4.2.0.
In a fresh Docker container of Ubuntu 22.04 updated to R 4.4.0:
# R CMD config CXX
g++ -std=gnu++17
#

as expected as gcc / g++ version 11 is good enough.  A good check is use a minimal RcppArmadillo example such as
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat simple(arma::vec x) {
    return x * x.t();
}
/*** R
simple(1:3)
*/

which, when built via Rcpp::sourceCpp("armaex.cpp", verbose=TRUE) does get compiled via C++11 which looks like an oversight. In any event, you can override it easily for this use case too by setting a plugin as e.g. here for C++17:
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp17)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat simple(arma::vec x) {
    return x * x.t();
}
/*** R
simple(1:3)
*/

In the Docker container I use this shows more than a screen of detail (when verbose=TRUE is set) including
using C++ compiler: ‘g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0’
using C++17
g++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -fopenmp  -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"/tmp"     -fpic  -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/r-base-H8urij/r-base-4.4.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -c arma.cpp -o arma.o
g++ -std=gnu++17 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -o sourceCpp_2.so arma.o -fopenmp -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR

which shows that the setting takes effect overriding what the package (accidentally? over-eagerly?) sets.

The reason for this is the way that RcppArmadillo configures its C++ compilation settings. The default version with RcppArmadillo is gnu++11. The default setting from RcppArmadillo is applied by Rcpp.
If you specifically want it to use another version of the C++ compiler then there are a couple of ways to do this:

Add to environment Define the CXX_STD variable in the environment running R.

export CXX_STD=CXX14


Specify in code Add another directive to the .cpp file (just put this after the line // [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]).

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp14)]]

I don't have gnu++17 on my machine but both of the approaches above gave gnu++14 as the compiler for the latter .cpp file provided.

thank you for shedding some light on this. Do you know of any reason why the file builds successfully in Windows without setting the cpp14 flag?

I just had a look in Windows and it seems that whether i set cpp14 or not the compiler that is called is g++, without a version specified.

Check what version of g++ you've got installed on the Windows machine using g++ --version.

Can you show where you think RcppArmadillo sets 'gnu++11'?  I do not see it in the sources.  Setting it for R instead aligns more with how I read Writing R Extensions.

I think I found it. This is specific to the use of Rcpp::sourceCpp() here and will not affect you in more general use of the package.

@AdaLovelace can you include what you found about "specific to the use of Rcpp::sourceCpp()" in your answer please?

@Alex It is not really relevant. It is an old and now superfluous line in the plugin generator which I think may disappear now as upstream seems to have seen this. The key aspect is shown in my answer and shows you how to set the level you really want (via a plugin).  An updated RcppArmadillo may remove the need for that.

Hi @AdaLovelace, the aspect of your answer which I found very useful is "this is set by R as described in Writing R Extensions" followed by "... what the package (accidentally? over-eagerly?) sets". It is my opinion that the two links you have included above are vital pieces for an answer to my question and I wish you would include them in your answer. At some level I already suspected that it was an issue with RcppArmadillo + knew that setting the plugin resolved my problem, what I could not understand was why it was happening. Thank you for throwing some light on the latter.
